ARM Intrinsic: Insert complex zero after each complex float sample
I have the following input:
[1i+2j], [3i+4j], [5i+6j],...

The output should be:
[1i+2j], [0i+0j], [3i+4j], [0i+0j], [5i+6j], [0i+0j],...

I wrote the following code:
void Extract (ComplexFloat *pIn, ComplexFloat*pOut, uint32_t N)
{
    ComplexFloat* pSrc = pIn;
    ComplexFloat *pDst = (ComplexFloat*)pOut;
    float32x2_t Zero;
    float32x4_t In, Out;
    float32x2_t HighIn, LowIn;

    Zero = vdup_n_f32 (0);

    //Loop on all input elements 
    for (int n = 0; n < N >> 1; n++)
    {
        In = vld1q_f32((float*)pSrc);
        HighIn = vget_high_f32(In);
        LowIn = vget_low_f32(In);
        Out = vcombine_f32(LowIn, Zero);
        vst1q_f32((float*)pDst, Out);
        pDst += 2;
        Out = vcombine_f32(HighIn, Zero);
        vst1q_f32((float*)pDst, Out);
        pDst += 2;
        pSrc += 2;
    }

}

Can you suggest a code with better performance ?
Thank you,
Zvika

So you just want to interleave 64-bit elements with zeros?  In 32-bit mode there should be a single instruction like vzip or vuzp that will interleave two vectors and produce 2 result vectors.  In AArch64 state you'd need separate instructions for each half, like uzp and uzp2.

Or the way clang chooses to do it in 32-bit mode, https://godbolt.org/z/TvTjas4M4 , it loads with vld1.32 {d1, d2}, [r0]! into a pair of 64-bit d registers then uses 2x vorr to copy one to the low half of a pair, then zero d3 (to go with d2).  But we should be able to avoid at least one of those copies since apparently vld1.32 can already write to an odd,even pair of d regs, so the high half of your source data becomes the low half of a q reg that could be already zeroed.  If you can load a discontiguous pair of d regs, you could avoid even that.

Or if 128-bit vectors stores can take an arbitrary pair of d regs, you could just do one load into a pair of d regs then two stores each using one half of the load and one already-zeroed d reg.  It probably depends a lot on the microarchitecture what's optimal, like if a pair of q regs is actually best on wider hardware.  And I wouldn't have much hope of getting a compiler to emit optimal asm for 32-bit ARM; they're notoriously bad at partial-register shenanigans to avoid data-movement instructions.

Are there any specific microarchitectures you care about optimizing for?  Like Cortex-M7 or Cortex-A76?  You are targeting 32-bit mode I'm assuming from the tags lacking [arm64]?

Peter - Thank you very much !

Does SIMD really help here? This is such a trivial transformation that I'd guess that even the naive scalar implementation could still saturate your memory bandwidth. Memory should be the bottleneck here, not the CPU.

At least the following should give fewer instructions:
void interleave(float *src, float *dst, int blocks) {
  uint64x2x2_t data = { vdupq_n_u64(0), vdupq_n_u64(0) };
  do {
     data.val[0] = vreinterpretq_u64_f32(vld1q_f32(src)); src += 4;
     vst2q_u64(reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(dst), data); dst += 8;
  } while (--blocks);
}


We need to cast two adjacent floats a wider 64-bit element, after which we can use vst2 to interleave 64 bits at a time with no explicit zip instructions.

Aki - Thank you very much !
